# Draw lines with rough edges in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, stroke, brush

Does anyone know an easy way to draw lines with irregular borders in Photoshop? I'd like to do something similar to the rectangular frame that surrounds the title and author in the following book cover:

[image: Cover of Una Vida Violenta by Pier Paolo Pasolini]

Comment: I usually find its easiest to look for a sketched line on shutterstock (or scan a pen stroke) and then photoshop it to the shape you want. – Using brushes works too but looks not as natural.

Answer (score 1):

There are brushes in Photoshop which can be used to stroke a path --

- Draw a path (not a shape, a path).
- Grab the `Brush Tool`
- Select a brush
- Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down and hit the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

[image]

Or...

It's possible to draw a standard rectangle, add a mask, then distress the mask.

[image]